# How to display error message if username already exists in meteor-ionic

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have used the [Meteor Ionic Demo](https://github.com/meteoric/demo) code to create my new application. Now, instead of signing up with an e-mail address, I want to use usernames.

I used this code ([source](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#custom-validation)):

```
// server/methods.js
if (Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.methods({
        "userExists": function(username){
            return !!Meteor.users.findOne({username: username});
        },
    });
}

// lib/config/at_config.js
AccountsTemplates.addField({
    _id: 'username',
    type: 'text',
    required: true,
    func: function(value){
        if (Meteor.isClient) {
            console.log("Validating username...");
            var self = this;
            Meteor.call("userExists", value, function(err, userExists){
                if (!userExists)
                    self.setSuccess();
                else
                    self.setError(userExists);
                self.setValidating(false);
            });
            return;
        }
        // Server
        return Meteor.call("userExists", value);
    },
    errStr: "Bad username"
});
```

Now the problem is, if the username already exists, how can I display an error message?

Currently, it displays only the ionic error icon, but not the `errStr`:

[image: meteor-ionic-username-in-use]

I think the problem is that I should return `userExists` in `func`, but how can I wait on the `userExists` method server call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function passed to `Meteor.call("userExists", value, function(err, userExists){` is the callback that will be called when the server method returns a response, so you are already waiting for it to finish.

From the source code of [meteor-useraccounts/core](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core), it seems that `errStr` is only used when `func` returns `true`. In your case, because the call to server is async, `func` is returning `undefined` which is considered ***'no error'***.

Also, what is shown next to the icon is the status of the field, and that status is modified by `setError`.

If you pass the error message to `setError`, it will be displayed correctly.

The solution is to change:

```
self.setError(userExists);
```

to:

```
self.setError("Bad username");
```